# Render CSV data using react-window or react-virtualized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

I am trying to render CSV data (sampleCSVData) using react-window. I am splitting the data using "," and then trying to populate it in a Cell component. To properly populate in Cell component I need a series like 0,1,2,3,4,5... which should change to a new row after 13 counts. I am not able to figure out this code:

**See this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/csvreact-window-9wg7z?file=/index.js).**

```js
const Cell = ({ columnIndex, rowIndex, style }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={
        columnIndex % 2
          ? rowIndex % 2 === 0
            ? "GridItemOdd"
            : "GridItemEven"
          : rowIndex % 2
          ? "GridItemOdd"
          : "GridItemEven"
      }
      style={style}
    >
      {rowIndex} {columnIndex} - {finalData[columnIndex]}
    </div>
  );
```

Current Outcome:
[image: Current Outcome]

Expected Outcome:
[image: Expected Outcome 1]
OR
[image: Expected Outcome 2]

Currently, I am using the below code to render the table, it's working fine but it's not very efficient.

```html
<CsvToHtmlTable
  data={sampleCSVData.slice(sampleCSVData.search(",result"), pingData.length)}
  csvDelimiter=","
  />
```